# Testing App Actions with Google Assistant

Tags: android, app-actions

I would like to test my app actions for the Google Assistant on my phone by actually using the Google Assistant rather than the App Action Testing Tool for Android Studio.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do so? Is there a way to do so without releasing the App into the PlayStore or do I have to do that in order to get the App Actions working with the Assistant itself?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Publish the app to the Play store, minimally in an internal testing track, as described in the documentation.
2. Use the provided test tool plugin.

There are no other supported ways to test your actions.  This is because App Actions requires the Assistant backend to be aware of your app and its configuration.  Both of these two options do that.  There is no device-side only support.